# Trying to setup sudo user

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, sudo

I'm trying to setup sudo without no password but still I get prompted for password, I'm using ubuntu, here is the relevant line from the sudoers configuration file :

```
gandalf ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: sudoers file should have mode 0440

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
gandalf ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I'm not sure if yours will work. If the above doesn't work, please provide entire content of file.

This should be placed after any group settings that would affect the user. If `gandalf` was in the group `sudo`, `/etc/sudoers` should read:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
gandalf ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I tried this after answering the same thing and was prompted for a password afterward.

Comment: I have it as `username ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL`. Looks like `(ALL)` is not needed. I think it means as any user, (ALL:ALL) means any user, any group and should work as well.

Comment: @Rob, so what is the entire content of your sudoers file please? There must be an error it somewhere else or something else is wrong, as that syntax is definitely correct.

Comment: @grifferz http://sprunge.us/jaGS

Comment: Oh, %wheel is overriding it, I bet.